# Stop Firebase from adding index number of ObservableCollection

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know how I can stop Real Time Firebase from adding the index of an observable collection as a title? All code is listed below along with how the data is shown in Firebase.

How data is presented in Firebase:

[image: how data is presented in firebase]

Index 0 is added to the DB as title '0'

[image]

```
//Await task that post the code to firebase 
public static async Task AddExercise(ObservableCollection<Exercise> exercisepassed)
{
    await Client.Child("exercises").PostAsync(exercisepassed);
}
```

Code that get sent to await task :

```
addexercise1.Add(new Exercise
        {
            id = uniqeexid,  
            title = title, 
            UserId = uid,  
            DurationMinutes = durationMinutes,
            StartDate = startdate,  
            NotificationIds = notificationIds,
            Time = time,  
            VideoId = videoId, 
            Often = often, 
            exerciseid = exid  });  

   await DbFirebase.AddExercise(addexercise1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the `-N7...` type keys, call `PutAsync` instead of `PostAsync`.

If you want to get rid of the `0`, then don't post a `ObservableCollection<Exercise>`, but instead post a single `Exercise` object.

Comment: i cant upvote because of my reputation but that solved it. thanks